# Why can't I see my own questions on the Stack Overflow main page?

Tags: discussion

On some Stack Exchange sites, immediately after making a post I can click on the main icon for the site and see my question show up at the top of the questions page.  But on Stack Overflow it doesn't show up in any of the views.  If I load from another browser that I am not logged in to, I immediately see my question.

Why can't I see it when logged in? It is useful to be able to watch it from the main page as I can see how many views I have without possibly registering false views by looking at it myself.  (I don't think this is supposed to happen, but it seems like sometimes when I reload a page it immediately jumps up by one even when it hasn't changed at all in a long time.)

Incidentally I *can* see my own posts on Meta Stack Overflow...

Comment: Is this a problem?

Comment: SO gets 8,000 questions a day, think of how fast main page scrolls

Comment: Caching. Number of questions. Take your pick, it's one of these.

Comment: If you want to see your own questions in a page view while logged in, sort by Newest based on a question tag.

Comment: @gnat Yes, but even when the newest item on the list is "1 min ago" and the oldest is "4 min ago" I still don't see it when the post or edit is less than 3 minutes ago.

Comment: @Neocortex Possibly.  Sometimes I don't see my post from a not-logged-in browser as well, and when I am getting low page views and no comments/replies I am concerned that nobody else is seeing my post either.  This seems to happen only on updates and not the original post however.

Comment: @yellowantphil I've never dug into the site deep enough to realize there is such a thing as "favorite tags".

Comment: I was experiencing the same thing and ended up here. Then checked the flow and realized the site has become utterly useless for new questions. Some 15 pages of new questions in one hour. I posted a question with tags and all but no one appears to be even viewing it but me.

Answer (score 3):

Stack Overflow's "main page" by default has the Interesting tab selected, *not* the Newest tab. Your question may be newly asked, but that doesn't mean it qualifies to as "Interesting".

The Newest tab on Stack Overflow is located at https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=newest Your newly asked question should appear there, unless that page is cached.

Comment: Oddly, the "newest" tab doesn't show up for me unless I go directly to that URL.  And when not logged in, I did see my post show up right near the top under "Interesting".   Caching seems like a definite possibility.

Comment: I just updated a post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27415977/http-authorization-not-sent-for-resources-on-page and I don't see it show up on either page logged in or not now.  So unless SO doesn't bring a post to the top on edit or other activity like other SE sites, something weird is going on.